Is my Z790 i12900 build compatible with my Be Quiet! Straight Power 12 PSU?
While going through my first build I think I made a mistake.
There are 2 - 2x4 connectors on the top of the Gigabyte Z7900 Aorus Elite AX motherboard, but my Be Quiet! Straight Power 12 PSU supports only 2 - 2x2 connectors. From what I understand to be extra power for the CPU which is required for 12th generation and up I think; not certain on this.
I was looking for help with this and just and advice, really hope I didn't screw myself over, would suck to have to get a new PSU. Thanks!

Be Quiet! Straight Power 12 PSU Page.
Gigabyte Aorus Elite AX Z790 Motherboard Page.



According to PC Part Picker, the parts are compatible. https://uk.pcpartpicker.com/list/G4BTdH. Do you have the appropriate cables available from the PSU box?

The Bequiet 12 1000w power supply you linked has two connectors on it labelled P8, enough for both of your motherboard's "ATX_12V_2X4" a.k.a. EPS12V a.k.a. P8 CPU power connectors.

Judging by the side-on pic of the cables on the motherboard page there, it came with two cables to connect to these two P8's, one that has an 8-pin connector and one that has two 4-pin connectors next to each other that are conspicuously designed to fit together in an 8-pin connector if that's what you need.

The reason that connector is designed to split in two like this is just in case somebody buys the PSU to use with an old P4 era system that only has one 4-pin CPU power connector and has components in the way such that it doesn't physically have room to have the extra 4 pins from a cable with an 8-pin connector sticking off the side.
Incidentally this 8-pin power connector standard -- the Entry-Level Power Supply Specification (EPS) from the Server System Infrastructure Forum (see https://www.snia.org/standards/industry-reference for more info) -- is actually from the late 90s and started out being used in servers, but it's been used in higher end desktops since at least 2014, maybe earlier.
Picking out what's what
Since it's maybe not obvious to someone building a system for the first time, here's how to sort out these cables from this unlabelled side-on picture:

The bottom right cable labelled 600W is obviously for the PCIe 5.0 port labelled 600W.
The top left cable has too many pins to be anything but the main ATX motherboard cable. The top end with the 10x? and 2x? connectors is the motherboard side (they will commonly have this split to suit older pre-ATX12V-2.0 motherboards that only need the a 20-pin connection). The PSU side of the cable is also evidently split in the PSU design for whatever reason; obviously it fits the two connectors labelled MB.
For the two cables at the right end of the top row of cables, the top ends have 3x2 and 1x2 connectors -- these are for handling either 6-pin or 8-pin PCIe power. These clearly have 6x? connectors on the other end, which matches the 2 PSU ports labelled PCIe
The other three cables on the bottom row all have the same 5x? connection at one end, and of them, you can see that the connector at the top right of the right-hand cable is a 4-pin Molex from the distinctive bevels at the top (which are for e.g. powering drives without new-style SATA power connections), and the connector at the top right of the middle cable is a SATA power with its distinctive L-shape. These match the PSU's 3 5-pin connections labelled "drives".
By the process of elimination the remaining cables are the CPU 12V power cables; in the case of the top middle cable it's pretty obvious because nothing else would be split into two 4-pin connectors like this

